# jump to current step when reloading instead of resetting to first step using smartWizard

Tags: jquery, plugins, smart-wizard

Good day,

I have a webform that is using smartWizard and keepFormData scripts. The scenario is this: the form values stays until it is submitted so whenever the page is reloaded or closed, the form values stays. Please feel free to test the webform here: http://www.doityourselfdegree.com/planbuilder/

My question is, is it possible that the wizard resumes to the current progress or step before the page was reloaded or the user decided to close the page instead of resetting the progress to step 1?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!